# Brightness keys don't work on a Toshiba Satellite t110

Tags: 11.10, drivers, brightness

Ok well I have tried close to every single post about this problem that I could find and can not find a perm a fix for it.

The fn + brightness up/down buttons do not work at all they show it changing the brightness but it is still as max brightness and it starts to burn your eyes after a while.

What can I do to fix the problem?

I'm using the full desktop version of ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

In terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Look for the line that says this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Modify it as to say

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save the file, shut down the window and insert the following in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your laptop and (hopefully) it will work. I'm not guaranteeing anything, but this worked for my Acer and seems to work for a lot of models.