# Toshiba u840: Hotkeys don't work after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, 14.10

I've already tried the solutions presented here:

[Upgraded to 14.10, brightness control quit working - Intel HD 4400](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541525/upgraded-to-14-10-brightness-control-quit-working-intel-hd-4400)

and here:

[Brightness keys don't work on a Toshiba Satellite t110](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104032/brightness-keys-dont-work-on-a-toshiba-satellite-t110)

with no results.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Same on Thinkpad T520